# How to correct the error: Output loop dead cycles on MDPI latex template

Tags: errors, logging, output-routine, mdpi

I was trying to format my submission paper to MDPI journal on Overleaf. I found that the [last template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/mdpi-article-template/fcpwsspfzsph) for the journal dates to 16 Dec 2020. If I compile the template I found no error, but when adding my text (not using any special commands, nor redefined ones, just text, sections and subsections, tables and figures with captions and a couple of math equations) I found this loop error and I don't now what is the origin of this.

I tried to look at it on the log file (posted here) but not a clue of what could case such an error.
I could not post my tex file here, but the problem happens after adding 3 sections, some citations and a figure. I look to my .bib file and all the references were correctly defined as well my tables and figures. On the previous version of the template (Nov 2020) this error didn't happen.

Could you point me to the solution of this error? Thanks.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.9.10)  22 DEC 2020 18:01
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**template.tex
(/compile/template.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-07-17> (/compile/Definitions/mdpi.cls
Document Class: Definitions/mdpi 12/14/2020 MDPI paper class
...
Package newfloat Info: `float' package detected.
Package caption Info: Begin \AtBeginDocument code.
Package caption Info: End \AtBeginDocument code.

Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 69.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `subscript' on input line 69.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 69.

Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 736786 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-mdpi-eps-converted-to.pdf
>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:34
(epstopdf)                    size: 44155 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-mdpi-eps-c
onverted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-mdpi.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
<Definitions/logo-mdpi-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=8, 88.33pt x 58.2175pt>
File: Definitions/logo-mdpi-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-mdpi-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-mdpi-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on in
put line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 43.16885pt x 28.45274pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <18> on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ppl on input line 6
9.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ppl.fd
File: ot1ppl.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ppl.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+zplm on input line 
69.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlzplm.fd
File: omlzplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OML/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+zplm on input line 
69.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omszplm.fd
File: omszplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMS/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+zplm on input line 
69.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxzplm.fd
File: omxzplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMX/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 18.75613pt on input line 69.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg
File: mt-msa.cfg 2006/02/04 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (a) (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 14.25455pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 11.25378pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 18.75613pt on input line 69.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg
File: mt-msb.cfg 2005/06/01 v1.0 microtype config. file: AMS symbols (b) (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 14.25455pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 11.25378pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+zplm on input line 
69.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1zplm.fd
File: ot1zplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
)
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `zplm' (encoding: OT1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-eur.cfg
File: mt-eur.cfg 2006/07/31 v1.1 microtype config. file: AMS Euler Roman (RS)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.42007pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.91925pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.25204pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 10.42007pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.91925pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 6.25204pt on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
<Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf, id=10, 102.3825pt x 102.3825pt>
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:31
(epstopdf)                    size: 284378 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pd
f>
(epstopdf)                    date: 2020-12-22 18:00:35
(epstopdf)                    size: 12600 bytes
(epstopdf)             Command: <epstopdf --outfile=Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-
converted-to.pdf Definitions/logo-orcid.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 69.
Package epstopdf Info: Output file is already uptodate.
File: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf Graphic file (type pdf)
<use Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf>
Package pdftex.def Info: Definitions/logo-orcid-eps-converted-to.pdf  used on i
nput line 69.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 9.10509pt x 9.10466pt.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.29405pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.21004pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 7.29405pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 5.21004pt on input line 69.

Overfull \hbox (1.63684pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 Ciais, P. The po-ten-tial of low-cost tin- 
 []


Overfull \hbox (10.38043pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 0.  [][] $https : / / dx . doi . org / 1 0 . 3 3 9 0 / atmos 1 
 []


Overfull \hbox (8.51083pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 tral with re-gard to ju-ris-dic-tional claims 
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for TS1+ppl on input line 6
9.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ts1ppl.fd
File: ts1ppl.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for TS1/ppl.
)
Overfull \hbox (3.97473pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 ble open ac-cess pub-li-ca-tion un-der the 
 []


Overfull \hbox (0.50304pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 terms and con-di-tions of the Cre-ative 
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.92104pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 Com-mons At-tri-bu-tion (CC BY) li-cense 
 []


Overfull \hbox (15.74872pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 69--69
\T1/ppl/m/n/7 ([][] $https : / / creativecommons . org / licenses / 
 []

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.33606pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 8.33606pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msa/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.37807pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `U/msb/m/n' will be
(Font)              scaled to size 9.37807pt on input line 69.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+cmss on input line 6
9.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmss.fd
File: t1cmss.fd 2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
Package microtype Info: Loading generic protrusion settings for font family
(microtype)             `cmss' (encoding: T1).
(microtype)             For optimal results, create family-specific settings.
(microtype)             See the microtype manual for details.

...
! Output loop---200 consecutive dead cycles.
\par ...af \global \holdinginserts \thr@@ \@@@par 
                                                  \ifnum \prevgraf >\linenop...
l.113 \section{Results}
                       
I've concluded that your \output is awry; it never does a
\shipout, so I'm shipping \box255 out myself. Next time
increase \maxdeadcycles if you want me to be more patient!

[5{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig02' on page 5 undefined on input line 115.

<fig02.png, id=27, 722.7pt x 505.89pt>
File: fig02.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig02.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig02.png  used on input line 118.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 239.0034pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig03' on page 5 undefined on input line 128.

<fig03.png, id=28, 722.7pt x 505.89pt>
File: fig03.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig03.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig03.png  used on input line 133.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 239.0034pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig04' on page 6 undefined on input line 138.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Press1990' on page 6 undefined on input line 
138.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `figA1' on page 6 undefined on input line 138.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Hagan2014' on page 6 undefined on input line 
138.

<fig04.png, id=29, 395.7987pt x 309.3156pt>
File: fig04.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig04.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig04.png  used on input line 141.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 266.8369pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig05' on page 7 undefined on input line 146.

<fig05.png, id=30, 1121.8713pt x 1030.0884pt>
File: fig05.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig05.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig05.png  used on input line 155.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 313.49278pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `T01' on page 8 undefined on input line 159.


Overfull \hbox (57.75618pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 165--196
[][] 
 []


Overfull \hbox (81.03795pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 165--196
[] 
 []


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig06' on page 8 undefined on input line 201.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig06' on page 8 undefined on input line 201.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig06' on page 8 undefined on input line 201.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig06' on page 8 undefined on input line 201.

<fig06.png, id=31, 1210.2816pt x 1068.3915pt>
File: fig06.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig06.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig06.png  used on input line 204.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 301.3973pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig06' on page 10 undefined on input line 208.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Casey2019' on page 10 undefined on input line
 210.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Collier-Oxandale2018a' on page 10 undefined o
n input line 210.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig08' on page 10 undefined on input line 213.

<fig08.png, id=32, 1082.1228pt x 1045.2651pt>
File: fig08.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig08.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig08.png  used on input line 216.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 329.80254pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig07' on page 11 undefined on input line 220.

<fig07.png, id=33, 1198.9593pt x 547.0839pt>
File: fig07.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig07.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig07.png  used on input line 223.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 155.7953pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `figA3' on page 11 undefined on input line 227.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `figA4' on page 11 undefined on input line 227.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `figA3' on page 12 undefined on input line 231.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `figA4' on page 12 undefined on input line 231.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `figA5' on page 12 undefined on input line 231.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig09' on page 12 undefined on input line 234.

<fig09.png, id=34, 1482.9804pt x 728.9634pt>
File: fig09.png Graphic file (type png)
<use fig09.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: fig09.png  used on input line 237.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 341.43306pt x 167.82489pt.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig09' on page 13 undefined on input line 241.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig09' on page 13 undefined on input line 241.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `TA1' on page 13 undefined on input line 241.


LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig03' on page 13 undefined on input line 243.

! Output loop---200 consecutive dead cycles.
\par ...af \global \holdinginserts \thr@@ \@@@par 
                                                  \ifnum \prevgraf >\linenop...
l.244 
      
I've concluded that your \output is awry; it never does a
\shipout, so I'm shipping \box255 out myself. Next time
increase \maxdeadcycles if you want me to be more patient!

[13
! Undefined control sequence.
\contentsline ...up \Hy@safe@activestrue \edef \x 
                                                  {\endgroup \def \noexpand ...
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\contentsline ...noexpand \Hy@tocdestname {#4}}\x 
                                                  \ifx \Hy@tocdestname \ltx@...
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\find@pdflink ...ode \protected@edef \Hy@testname 
                                                  {#2}\ifx \Hy@testname \@em...
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@tocdestname 
                           
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...meFilter \expandafter {\Hy@testname 
                                                  }
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@testname 
                        
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Hy@testname 
                        
l.244 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\reserved@a ->\def \reserved@a 
                               *{\@refstar }\reserved@a 
l.244 
      
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.

 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 28601 strings out of 480906
 492502 string characters out of 5908280
 924965 words of memory out of 5000000
 43533 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 593674 words of font info for 232 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,18n,64p,2877b,917s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Welcome to the party... had the same problem. It seems that the float placement parameters that they use create often impossible pages. So I decided to use `\clearpage` --- put one after the last or next-to-last figure before the error line. Rinse, repeat. The output will not be really nice, but they will fix it on publication...

Comment: I have to say that the template is quite bad. Remember also to put a `\end{paracol}` before the bibliography (!) (the corresponding `\begin` is put in by the template at the start of the document)

Comment: with no test file debugging isn't really possible but the first thing to try is put `\maxdeadcycles=500` in the preamble as you are being cut off at 200. It may be that you are looping and increasing it to any amount does not help, just makes it take longer to stop but that is first thing to try

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have a MWE, but it's not exactly minimal... https://gist.github.com/Rmano/a51283186c4840f4cb0f489432545bdd (you need the directory `Definitions` from the MDPI template linked by the OP)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle with 500 as limits it seems it works... (also on my original paper!)

Comment: **Always read error messages!!** :-) You know the suggestion to increase `\maxdeadcycles` is explicitly in the text you posted to your question:-)

Comment: @Rmano sorry: I  just noticed you posted that not the OP :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ;-) but I *did* read the **documentation** and there was no hint there... :-P

Answer (score 2):

The error message help text you posted says

```
I've concluded that your \output is awry; it never does a
\shipout, so I'm shipping \box255 out myself. Next time
increase \maxdeadcycles if you want me to be more patient!
```

in comments it is suggested that it works with a value of 500, so putting

```
\maxdeadcycles=500
```

in the preamble.

Comment: but that sounds seriously weird :-)

Comment: thanks for your answers, but increasing the `\maxdeadcycles` did not solve the problem, same output is generated. I think this is related to the template.

Comment: @Riverarodrigoa since you have not provided any example that shows the problem have to guess. As I said increasing this may help but if you are in a loop it may not finish however large you set it. If you edit your question to provide a test case we can look....

Comment: @FrankMittelbach yes my guess it's in an infinite loop but comments under the questiion indicate this is enough in some cases, and the class increases the default from 100 to 200 so they must be sort of expecting this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Applied Science template, on 141 line. And I decided to submit manuscript on MS Word template.

(You have used the same label more than once. Check that each \label{...} labels only one item.).

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/216997)